# File upload in jsp using Apache commons

Tags: jsp, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file in jsp using Apache commons fileupload. The code i am using currently is:

```
String filePath=request.getContextPath()+"pics";
if (fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0) 
     {
           file = new File(filePath+fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
     } else {
          file = new File(filePath+ fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+ 1));
             }
                            fi1.write(file);
```

I am confused in specifying the path for this file. Everything works good if i use this path:

```
String filePath="C:\\Users\\Somye\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\A.K\\web\\pics\\";
```

But my need is by using request.getContextPath(); 
 Any solution??

Comment: Change:
`String filePath=request.getContextPath()+"pics";`
TO
`String filePath=request.getContextPath()+"/pics/";`
Hope it'll help..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String filePath=request.getContextPath()+"pics";
```

to

```
String filePath=request.getContextPath()+File.separator+"pics"+File.separator;
```